# PHP/ADO Registration Submission

Tags: php, pdo

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
> error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'cust_b_country' at
> row 1 in C:\wamp\www\ecommerce-website-master\registration.php on line
>
> 163 ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect
> integer value: '' for column 'cust_b_country' at row 1 in
> C:\wamp\www\ecommerce-website-master\registration.php on line 163

```
 // saving into the database
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_customer (
                                        cust_name,
                                        cust_cname,
                                        cust_email,
                                        cust_phone,
                                        cust_country,
                                        cust_address,
                                        cust_city,
                                        cust_state,
                                        cust_zip,
                                        cust_b_name,
                                        cust_b_cname,
                                        cust_b_phone,
                                        cust_b_country,
                                        cust_b_address,
                                        cust_b_city,
                                        cust_b_state,
                                        cust_b_zip,
                                        cust_s_name,
                                        cust_s_cname,
                                        cust_s_phone,
                                        cust_s_country,
                                        cust_s_address,
                                        cust_s_city,
                                        cust_s_state,
                                        cust_s_zip,
                                        cust_password,
                                        cust_token,
                                        cust_datetime,
                                        cust_timestamp,
                                        cust_status
                                    ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $statement->execute(array(
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_name']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_cname']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_email']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_phone']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_country']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_address']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_city']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_state']),
                                        strip_tags($_POST['cust_zip']),
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        '',
                                        md5($_POST['cust_password']),
                                        $token,
                                        $cust_datetime,
                                        $cust_timestamp,
                                        0
                                    ));
```

Comment: **Do not** use `md5` to hash passwords. It is very insecure and PHP's built-in `password_hash` and `password_verify` are easy to implement and up-to-date with modern security standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cust_b_country` is an integer field, according to the error. So you cannot set it to an empty string (`''`) as you are doing. Either set it to `NULL` (if the column allows NULLs), or to some value such as `0`. Or if it has a default value configured, just don't include it in the `INSERT` query at all, and then it'll get its default value automatically.

Answer (score -1):

It says $_POST['cust_country'] is not an integer value

You can try `(int) $_POST['cust_country']` to convert variable type to integer

Comment: Still It is not working